# What's the difference between calling Double.valueOf(String s) and new Double(String s)?

Tags: java

So I've got a String and I want to create a Double object with the String as a value.

I can call

`Double myDouble = new Double (myString);`

or I can call

`Double myDouble = Double.valueOf(myString);`

Is there a difference? I'm guessing the first guarantees a new object is created on the heap and the second *might* re-use an existing object.

**For extra credit**: the string might be *null*, in which case I want the Double to be *null*, but both the above throw a NullPointerException. Is there a way of writing

`Double myDouble = myString == null ? null : Double.valueOf(myString);`

in less code?

Comment: *How* do you want to give extra credits?? You're limited to *one* upvote to each answer ;-)

Comment: *I'm guessing the first guarantees a new object is created on the heap and the second might re-use an existing object.* you're guessing correctly :-)

Comment: @Andreas_D - I was thinking maybe USD 1,000,000 paid into someone's PayPal account, but you're right: Stack Overflow rep is far more valuable, so I withdraw that offer ;-]

Comment: From Java 9 onward, `new Double(String)` and other similar constuctor calls are deprecated because `valueOf` (or methods like `parseDouble` for making primitives) are "likely to yield significantly better space and time performance" in the newer JDK implementations.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Depends on the implementation. [openJDK 6 b14](http://grepcode.com/file/repository.grepcode.com/java/root/jdk/openjdk/6-b14/java/lang/Double.java#Double.%3Cinit%3E%28java.lang.String%29) uses this implementation of `Double(String s)`:

```
this(valueOf(s).doubleValue());
```

So it calls `valueOf(String s)` internally and *must* be less efficient compared to calling that method directly.

Comment: Accepting this answer because it starts with the phrase "Depends on the implementation", which it seems from the other answers is actually the case.

Answer (score 3):

Your assumption is right. The second way of getting a Double out of String can be faster because the value may be returned from a cache.

Regarding the second question, you may create a helper null safe method which would return a null instead of throwing NullPointerException.

Answer (score 3):

from apache

```
public static Double valueOf(String string) throws NumberFormatException {
          return new Double(parseDouble(string));
}
```

&

```
public Double(String string) throws NumberFormatException {
          this(parseDouble(string));
}
```

from sun[oracle ] jdk

```
 public Double(String s) throws NumberFormatException {
    // REMIND: this is inefficient
    this(valueOf(s).doubleValue());
    }
```

&

```
public static Double valueOf(double d) {
        return new Double(d);
    }
```

Comment: Is this actual source code from a particular JVM implementation? Might help to identify which one.

Answer (score 2):

No difference whatsoever, at least in Oracle JDK 1.6:

```
public Double(String s) throws NumberFormatException {
// REMIND: this is inefficient
this(valueOf(s).doubleValue());
}
```

Comment: The difference is in the comment. valueOf() creates one Double object, new Double() creates two.

Answer (score 0):

If you are concerned about performance you should consider using a primitive.

```
double myDouble = Double.parseDouble(myString);
```

Comment: Makes it harder to pass the all-important null values around, though. (Please don't suggest passing NaNs!)

Answer (score 0):

this will either return a valid Double, or null otherwise.

```
Double myDouble = null;
try {
    myDouble = Double.valueOf(myString);
}
catch (Exception e) { }
```

it handles even when myString is null